# How do I create an Alfred workflow to search for my own, most recent posts on google plus?

Tags: search, hyperlink, google-plus, alfred

I am trying to build an Alfred workflow to search for my own, most recent posts on google plus. The hyperlink for a search is pretty easy https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/ , but how do I restrict it to my own and most recent posts? I can do this manually by selecting my own and most recent, but that doesn't change the corresponding hyperlink.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`activities.list` API call](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) with your user ID (which can be found in the link to your Google+ profile). This will return your public posts, sorted by recency.